# Filter columns based on a value (Pandas): TypeError: Could not compare ['a'] with block values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying filter a DataFrame columns based on a value.

```
In[41]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a',2,3,4,5], 'B':[6,7,8,9,10]})
In[42]: df
Out[42]: 
   A   B
0  a   6
1  2   7
2  3   8
3  4   9
4  5  10
```

Filtering columns:

```
In[43]: df.loc[:, (df != 6).iloc[0]]
Out[43]: 
   A
0  a
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5
```

It works! But, When I used strings,

```
In[44]: df.loc[:, (df != 'a').iloc[0]]
```

I'm getting this error: `TypeError: Could not compare ['a'] with block values`

Comment: This won't work for mixed dtypes as you've found, the implementation currently doesn't support comparison of a df where any of the columns are pure numeric types, you'd have to filter the df first to give you just the object dtype columns in order for the error to not be raised

Comment: @EdChum: Thanks for pointing that out. Makes sense..

Comment: I know this is an old question but I think they fixed it in either `pandas 0.21.0` or `0.22.0`. I did this by mistake in my test venv and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compare string 'a' with numeric values in column B.

If you want your code to work, first promote dtype of column B as numpy.object, It will work.

```
df.B = df.B.astype(np.object)
```

Always check data types of the columns before performing the operations using

```
df.info()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with masks instead, for example:

```
df[df.A!='a'].A
```

and to filter from any column:

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: sum([x_=='a' for x_ in x])==0, axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the fact that there are numeric and string objects in the dataframe. 
You can loop through each column and check each column as a series for a specific value using

(Series=='a').any()