# Replace the text by blank spaces in cells that do not contain a specific word .xlsx in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a **strong text**.xlsx file with several cols and thousand rows. I need to delete the text from the cells that do not contain  the word `student`
I tried with the following but it didn't work so far, it deletes all the column:

```
df.loc[~df["Column1"].str.contains('student',case=True),'Column1']=' '
```

Comment: Please put a small sample of your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try if this one works.

```
for col in df.columns:
    if (df[col] != 'student').any():
        df[col+"_mv"] = df[col].replace('student', '')
```

This creates a new column with all `student` replaced with blank space. You can later drop the old column. I am not sure if you could use `df[col] = df[col].replace('student', '')`, you can check that as well.

Comment: I get the following: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-c392c9462213> in <module>
      1 for col in df.columns:
----> 2     if (df[col] != 'col').any():
      3         df[col]=df[col].replace('student','')

/anaconda3/envs/Python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py in wrapper(self, other, axis)
   1281 
   1282             with np.errstate(all='ignore'):
-> 1283                 res = na_op(values, other)
   1284             if is_scalar(res):
   1285                 raise TypeError('Could not compare {typ} ty...

Comment: I guess your column contains numerical values. Add `df.B = df.B.astype(np.object)` to convert to numpy objects. More on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40515418/filter-columns-based-on-a-value-pandas-typeerror-could-not-compare-a-wit)